# php login not being redirected

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I hope someone can help me. I am trying to redirect the user back to the index page once they have successfully logged in. I can only see a white blank screen with no errors.

Thanks for your help

```
<?php 
include('includes/functions.php');

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users_cust WHERE username = $username") or die(mysql_error());
            $user = mysql_fetch_array($query);

            if(md5($_POST['password']) == $user['password']) {
                echo("Login Successful!");
                $_SESSION['user'] = $user['username'];
                header("Location:/index.php") or die(mysql_error());
        } else {
            echo("Please check your login details");
            include('login.php');
        }
        } else {
            echo("Please check your password");
            include('login.php');
        }
    } else {
        echo("Please check your username");
        include('login.php');
    }
} else {
    echo("Please check that you filled out the login form");
    include('login.php');
}

?>
```

AND my main login page like this

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
header("Location:index.php");
} else {?>

<html>

<head>
    <title> Login Area
    </title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="dologin.php" method="post">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username">
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I Think your problem is that you haven't got a session called 'user' ? I think you need to change this to 'username'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users_cust WHERE username = $username") or die(mysql_error());
```

Should the query part be like this:

```
...WHERE username = '$username'"
```

Comment: possibly however that doesn't make a difference! Appreciate your help!!

Comment: What about your form? Could this be happening because you haven't labelled the ids for each text box? Try adding an id attr to each of the fields instead of just the name attr

Comment: it actually seems you are correct with your first answer!! '' are needed around my $username! New problem is saying the details are incorrect, which they are not. Seems like the connection to my database is wrong somewhere! Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You have no session called 'user' and therefore this session will constantly return no value, I believe it needs updating to this..

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you could create a new session called 'LoggedIN', In your code on the first page add this bit of code in..

```
$_SESSION['LoggedIN'] = true;
```

Which would go below your previous session

Then on your second page, you can simply put:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LoggedIN']) && $_SESSION['LoggedIN'] == true) {
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't do anything. I actually changed user to username while trying to fix the issue. Thanks for bringing that up!!

Comment: I Guess you could alternatively just create a new session, setting it to be true or false, i'll update my answer with what I mean, 2 mins.

Comment: @SteveAylward I'm guessing it didn't solve your problem?

Comment: hey sorry man no it actually didnt!! It just simply wont redirect after loggin in

Comment: Ahh.. Sorry about that, it should work though, I've got the same for my website and it works fine ;(

Answer (score 0):

On your first page you have $_SESSION['username'], while on the other is $_SESSION['user'].

Decide on using one of them and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try header("Location: index.php");

instead of header("Location:/index.php") or die(mysql_error()); exit();

and on your second page check for $_SESSION['username'] instead of $_SESSION['user']

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `$_SESSION['user']` in your 1st page, I think you need to change it to `$_SESSION['username']` and that should make it fine!

And as a side note, I always thought doing validation using javascript is best!

Comment: this didnt actually work! I still have a white screen that will no redirect after it processes dologin.php